# How to determine probability of 0 to N events occurring given probability of each of those N events?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, recursion, probability

First time posting here, so if I make a mistake with something let me know and I'd be more than happy to fix it!

Given N events, each of which have an individual probability (from 0 to 100%) of occurring, I'd like to determine the probability of 0 to N of those events occurring together.

For example, if I have event 1, 2, 3,...,N and 5 (E1, E2, E3...,EN) where the individual probability of a specific event occurring is as follows:

- E1 = 30% probability of occurring
- E2 = 40% probability of occurring
- E3 = 50% probability of occurring
- ...
- EN = x% probability of occurring

I'd like to know the probability of having:

- none of these events occurring
- any 1 of these events occurring
- any 2 of these events occurring
- any 3 of these events occurring
- ...
- all N of these events occurring

I understand that having 0 events occurring is (1-E1)(1-E2)...(1-EN) and that having all N events occurring is E1*E2*...*E3. However, I do not know how to calculate the other possibilities (1 to N-1 events occurring).

I have been looking for some recursive algorithm (binomial compound distribution) that could solve this but I have not found any explicit formula that does this. Wondering if any of you guys could help!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The events are indeed **independent**.

Comment: (Care to comment on in/dependence?)

Comment: Given the OP stating what the probability of 0 events happening is, the events would have to be independent.

Comment: @grey Yes, they are independent. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of research and some help from the answers here, I've come up with the following code:

```
function [ prob_numSites ] = probability_activationSite( prob_distribution_site )

N = length(prob_distribution_site); % number of events
notProb = 1 - prob_distribution_site; % find probability of no occurrence
syms x; % create symbolic variable
prob_number = 1; % initializing prob_number to 1

for i = 1:N
    prob_number = prob_number*(prob_distribution_site(i)*x + notProb(i));
end

prob_number_polynomial = expand(prob_number); % expands the function into a polynomial
revProb_numSites = coeffs(prob_number_polynomial); % returns the coefficients of the above polynomial (ie probability of 0 to N events, where first coefficient is N events occurring, last coefficient is 0 events occurring)
prob_numSites = fliplr(revProb_numSites); % reverses order of coefficients
```

This takes in probability of certain number of individual events occurring and returns array of the probability of 0 to N events occurring.

([This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215021/probability-of-exactly-k-out-of-n-events-occuring) answer helped a lot).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Poisson binomial
[wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function).

There's an explicit recursive formula but beware of numerical stability. 
[image]

where

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute your own version of Pascal's triangle, with probabilities (instead of counts) in each location.  Row 0 will be the single figure 1.00; row 1 consists of two values, P(E1) and 1-P(E1).  Below that, in row k, each position is P(Ek)*[above-right entry] + (1-P(Ek))*[above-left entry].  I recommend a lower-triangular matrix for this, something like:

```
1.00
0.30 0.70
0.12 0.46 0.42  # These are 0.3*0.4 | 0.3*0.6 + 0.7*0.4 | 0.7*0.6
0.06 0.29 0.44 0.21  # 0.12*0.5 | 0.12*0.5 + 0.46*0.5 | ...
```

See how it works?  In array / matrix notation for a matrix M, given event probabilities in vector P, this looks something like

```
M[k, i] = P[k] * M[k-1, i] +
          (1-P[k]) * M[k-1, i] + P[k] * M[k-1, i-1]
```

The above is a nice recursive definition.  Note that my earlier "above-right" reference in the lower-matrix notation is simply a row above; above-left is exactly that: row k-1, column i-1.

When you're done, the bottom row of the matrix will be the probabilities of getting N, N-1, N-2, ... 0 of the events.  If you want these probabilities in the opposite order, then simply switch the coefficients P[k] and 1-P[k]

Does that get you moving toward a solution?

Comment: Hey Prune, thanks for the quick response! I do follow the explanation up until the recursive definition.

For example, if we're trying to find M[2,0] (ie. it should equal 0.12), then we'll have:

M[2,0] = M[1,0]*P[2] + M[1,0]*(1-P[2]) + M[1,1]*P[2]
           = (0.3*0.4) + (0.3*0.6) + (0.7*0.4)
           = 0.58 ?

Comment: Yup ... I screwed up my shifting.  Upper-left is still a diagonal; upper-right is directly above.  Please adjust subscripts accordingly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by this? Is it possible for you to show me what you mean in code?

Comment: I believe this still doesn't work for the M[2,0] example as your last term of M[k-1,i-1] refers to M[1,-1] which does not exist?

Comment: No, you still have to take care of edge cases.  You gave us a general algorithm problem, rather than partially correct code.  Thus, I gave you the generic pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following recursive program should work.

```
function ans = probability_vector(probabilities)
    if len(probabilities) == 0
        % No events can happen.
        ans = [1];
    elseif len(probabilities) == 1
        % 0 or 1 events can happen.
        ans = [1 - probabilities[1], probabilities[1]];
    else
        half = ceil(len(probabilities)/2);
        ans_half1 = probability_vector(probabilities[1: half]);
        ans_half2 = probability_vector(probabilities[half + 1: end]);
        ans = convolve(ans_half1, ans_half2)
    end
    return
end
```

And if `p` is a probability vector, then `p[i+1]` is the probability of `i` of the events happening.

See http://matlabtricks.com/post-3/the-basics-of-convolution for an explanation of the magic `conv` operator that does the meat of the work.

Comment: I understand most of your logic, however where does the 'probability_vector' come from? It seems like an undefined variable?

Comment: @aboublemc I don't have Matlab and have not tried to program in it for 20 years, so there may be obvious bugs.  But we want to wind up with a vector that is the probability of having 0 events, 1 event, 2 events, etc.  I'm trying to write a function that computes that based on the fact that for 0 or 1 events I know what the vector should be, and I know how to combine two of them.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers seemed to worked/was understandable for me so I computed it and made it myself in python:

```py
def combin(n, k):
   if k > n//2:
       k = n-k
   x = 1
   y = 1
   i = n-k+1
   while i <= n:
       x = (x*i)//y
       y += 1
       i += 1
   return x

# proba being the probability of each of the N evenments, each being different from one another.

for i in range(N,0,-1):
    print(i)
    if sums[i]> 0:
        continue
    print(combin(N,i))
    for j in itertools.combinations(proba, i):
        sums[i]+=np.prod(j) 
for i in range(N,0,-1):
    for j in range(i+1,N+1):
        icomb = combin(j,i)
        sums[str(i)] -= icomb*sums[str(j)]
```

the math is not super simple:

*Let $C_{w_n}$ be the set of all unordered sets $(i,j,k...n)$*

*where $i,j,k...n\in w$*

*$Co(i,proba) = sum{C_{w_i}} - sum_{u from i+1..n}{(u \choose i)* sum{C_{w_u}}}$*

*$Co(i, P)$ being the probability of i events occuring given $P = {p_i...p_n}$, the bernouilli probability of each event.*